# Access data from JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I want to read data from a JSON file in Nodejs. Suppose I have the following file:

```
{
"categories": [
{
    "title": "Music Awards",
    "subtitle": "Choose the category",
        "buttons": [{
            "type": "postback",
            "title": "Film Category",
            "payload": "category_film"
        }, {
            "type": "postback",
            "title": "Upcoming Category",
            "payload": "category_upcoming"
        },{
            "type": "postback",
            "title": "Technical Category",
            "payload": "category_technical"
        }
    ]
}
]
}
```

I have read and parsed the file.

```
var cat = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('selectcat.json', 'utf8'));
```

Now I am trying cat.categories but do not get anything.

Comment: works for me... please describe (by adding relevant code) what you are doing with `cat`.

Comment: In console I am getting, "[object Object]"

Comment: check if you are getting the file contents properly `fs.readFileSync('selectcat.json', 'utf8')`

Comment: Yaa file is being read properly, no issues there

Comment: By the way, you can actually just `require()` a JSON-formatted file and get back the parsed results. For example: `var cat = require('selectcat.json');`

Comment: @RakshitBhatnagar Can you paste your code for printing the output

Comment: I would like a solution with this approach only

Comment: @Prasanth  var fs = require("fs");
console.log("\n *STARTING* \n");
var contents = fs.readFileSync("selectcat.json");
var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents)
console.log("value" + jsonContent.categories);

console.log("\n *EXIT* \n");

Comment: change `console.log("value" + jsonContent.categories);` to `console.log( jsonContent.categories);`

Comment: @RakshitBhatnagar I highly recommend you read this text: `How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example` - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Till "subtitle" it works, now "[object Object]" is coming for "buttons", The data inside buttons is not coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's strange that you get `[object Object]` in the console. The max depth for `console.log` isn't reached by that data (at least not until `buttons`). If you do something like

```
var cat = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('f.json', 'utf8'));
console.log("cat: " + cat);
```

Then you are getting `[object Object]` because your string concatenation implicitly calls `toString()` on the object, and `[object Object]` is its representation.

If you however, just log

```
console.log(cat);
```

or

```
console.log("cat:", cat); // mind the comma
```

you'll get the data you'd expect.

Sidenote:

If you need to log the whole object with all the data, you can use node's `util`:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");
let cat = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('selectcat.json', 'utf8'));
console.log(util.inspect(cat, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
```

Comment: Not getting the data inside "buttons"

Comment: console.log() is for debugging purposes usually. The data is there, it's just not shown. @RakshitBhatnagar what do you want to do with the data? just loop over buttons if you insist on logging it

Comment: edited the answer with a way to show the whole object @RakshitBhatnagar